# SQL Server Database Encryption (Column Level)

Tags: sql-server, encryption

This is not an issue, but more a Question on an unknown topic for me.

A client of mine has asked to Encrypt some columns in the database, but from the application, he might see the values of the columns.

Any idea on how to start making my plan for this?

Comment: Read about the "always encrypted" feature. It is designed for exactly this.

Comment: give me time to implement always encrypted and i will revert. Seems the most suitable though.

Comment: one more question, am i able to permanently decrypt the data and switch the always encrypted to off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea on how to start making my plan for this?

Work with client about what are the threats you should protect the database.

always encrypted is great because it's the only feature to protect data from DBA (superuser) however it could break your application if it attempts to run inequality search for encrypted column.

Also encryption means someone have to manage encryption keys.

https://blog.netwrix.com/2019/06/13/sql-server-encryption-explained-tde-column-level-encryption-and-more/

Comment: can i encrypt columns from different tables within the same Encryption key?

Comment: You are talking about DECRYPTBYKEY? Yes. you can